# Why does HTTP request always take as long as the full timeout?

Tags: go, concurrency

I am making a _golang git bruteforcer. It's acting a bit weird, I guess it's got something to do with concurrency.
`sync.WaitGroup`

Here's the code  : https://dpaste.org/vO7y

```
package main

import { <snipped for brevity> }

// ReadFile : Reads File and returns it's contents
func ReadFile(fileName string) []string { <snipped for brevity> }

func joinString(strs ...string) string { <snipped for brevity> }

// MakeRequest : Makes requests concurrently
func MakeRequest(client *http.Client, url string, useragent string, ch chan<- string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    // start := time.Now()
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    request.Header.Set("User-Agent", useragent)
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    // secs := time.Since(start).Seconds()
    if response.StatusCode < 400 {
        // fmt.Printf("Time elapsed %f", secs)
        bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer response.Body.Close()
        bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
        notGit, err := regexp.MatchString("<html>", strings.ToLower(bodyString))
        if !notGit && len(bodyString) > 0 { // empty pages and html pages shouldn't be included
            fmt.Println(bodyString)
            ch <- fmt.Sprintf(" %s ", Green(url))
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    useragent := "Mozilla/10.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/538.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.420 Safari/537.36"
    gitEndpoint := []string{"/.git/", "/.git/HEAD", "/.gitignore", "/.git/description", "/.git/index"}
    timeout := 10 * time.Second
    var tr = &http.Transport{
        MaxIdleConns:      30,
        IdleConnTimeout:   time.Second,
        DisableKeepAlives: true,
        TLSClientConfig:   &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
        DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   timeout,
            KeepAlive: time.Second,
        }).DialContext,
    }
    re := func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        return http.ErrUseLastResponse
    }
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport:     tr,
        CheckRedirect: re,
        Timeout:       timeout,
    }
    output := ReadFile(os.Args[1])
    // start := time.Now()
    ch := make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, url := range output {
        for _, endpoint := range gitEndpoint {
            wg.Add(1)
            go MakeRequest(client, "https://"+url+endpoint, useragent, ch, &wg)
        }
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()
    f, err := os.OpenFile("git_finder.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    for val := range ch {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(Red(err))
        }
        _, err = fmt.Fprintln(f, val)
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
    f.Close()
    fmt.Printf("Total time taken %.2fs elapsed\n", time.Since(start).Seconds())
}
```

**Working :**

It reads the urls from a file and checks for `/.git, /.git/HEAD, /.git/description, /.git/index` on the webserver.

**Problem :**
If I change the `http.Client` timeout to `2 seconds` it will finish in 2 seconds, if it's 50 seconds it will wait till 50 seconds, it doesn't matter if the input file contains 10 urls or 500 urls.
My Understanding is if there's more number of urls it will wait till the timeout of last URL that's passed with the goroutine.

### Update 1 :

As adrian mentioned in the comments, it doesn't look like a concurrency problem, that's what one of the main issue with this is that I can't place a finger on what the exact problem is here

Comment: If it changes with client timeout, that would seem to be HTTP timeout related, not concurrency related, right? You're discarding the error from `client.Do`, which would seem to be very relevant here.

Comment: The major problem is I don't know what to look for , like what do I search on Google for this

Comment: SO is for help with programming problems, not for help Googling things... if you want help with your issue, see my previous comment. If you want help with Google searches, this is not the appropriate site for that.

Comment: THanks for pointing out that @Adrian , but if there was an issue the function would return, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Hence, I'm confused. Sorry, if I was unclear with 'google searches' but that's not what I'm seeking here for.

Comment: If your requests weren't timing out, changing the client timeout would have no impact. Your function returns no matter what, so I'm not sure how it could not be the case - it returns whether it succeeds or fails. In any case, you have an error check where you discard the error, you should be printing it so you can see what's going on when there's an error.

Comment: The program does not close the response body in all cases.  Move the statement `defer response.Body.Close()` to the line before the statement `if response.StatusCode < 400 {`

Comment: yup, that seems about right. I am trying that now and getting somewhere, will update as soon as I find something here. THanks again @Adrian

Comment: Add some logging to `MakeRequest` and run it with one or two urls. The behavior is consistent with creating many requests at the same time, and timing out all of them.

Comment: If you need to send parallel request, you can try my little library: https://github.com/alessiosavi/Requests. In the `example` folder you will find how to send parallel request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are reading URLs from a file, then firing requests in parallel to all those URLs, then waiting for all the parallel requests to finish.

So this actually makes sense and would not indicate an issue:

> If I change the http.Client timeout to 2 seconds it will finish in 2 seconds, if it's 50 seconds it will wait till 50 seconds, it doesn't matter if the input file contains 10 urls or 500 urls.

Let's say your file has 500 URLs.

You fire the 500 requests in parallel... then wait for all of them to finish (remember, they are all executing in parallel). How long would that take?

In the worst case (all of the requests timeout at 50 seconds), it will just take 50 seconds in total (since they are all waiting for those 50 seconds in parallel).

In the best case (all requests go through successfully with no timeouts) it should take a few seconds.

In the average case you are probably seeing (a few timeout at 50 seconds) then it takes 50 seconds (you will be waiting for those few requests to wait those 50 seconds in parallel as in the worst case).

Comment: This looks right. However what about if I put 1M requests, then total time would definitely be > 1 second ( assuming timeout is 1 second ) ?

Comment: My answer was assuming your 10 to 500 requests example, if you put 1M requests, depending on the resources of the machine you are using you might saturate the CPU and the memory, so it might either take a bit longer, fail with an out of memory error, etc. Assuming you don't run out of resources, with 1M requests probably the time for reading the file, and processing the results will start to play a role as well.

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit unsure about this and hence  asked. I assumed the answer would be on somewhat these lines too.